# Limiting behaviour of usual lengths of runs

Tags: combinatorics, analytic-combinatorics

From Flajolet/Segdewick's *Analytical Combinatorics* (p. 53) I have learned that 97% of the binary sequences of length 200 contain runs longer than 5. The other way around: 97% of the sequences contain no run longer than 11.

[image]

Let $a(n)$ be the minimal number $a$ such that 97% of the binary sequences of length n contain no run longer than $a$. Example: $a(200) = 11$

> What is the limiting behaviour of $a(n)$?

(in Big-O-notation).

A related question is:

> What is the limiting behaviour of the maximum $max(n)$?

Example. $max(200) = 7$.

Comment: Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: If this site is not appropriate for this question: could you give me an advice which other site might be? Thanks.

Comment: It's appropriate, It would just be nice to see your attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: I want to be honest: I am not a working (or even student) mathematician, but am strongly interested in the result. Unfortunately I do not have the time to delve deeper into the problem and its ways of solution. Even though I will be interested in the solution (not only the result).

Comment: Consider runs of length at least $l$. Sans boundary issues, each such a run is followed by an opposite coin flip, hence the probability that a given coin flip is one after the end of the run is $p=2\cdot 2^{-l-1}=2^{-l}$. This means that expected time to see a run of length at least $l$ (for $2^{-l}$ small) is distributed approximately as $\exp(p)$ and you can deduce quantiles from here: $P(\tau_l>N)\approx \exp(-N2^{-l})=1-q$ which yields $$l_q\approx\log_2 N-\log_2\log\frac 1{1-q}$$
but I would use this for small $q$'s.

Comment: See Proposition V.1 (ibid, p. 308).